# newid() and alias TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have this problem

```
select newId() as code1,
       newId() as code2,
       parentId as code1
```

but obviously this thing doesn't work how can i use the same random id twice in a SELECT?

Comment: Ummm....what is the point of getting the same value in two columns? You already have it in one column. If you need that value a second time for some reason just reference the same column again.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question but this selected the "same" random code twice.

```
;with cte as
(
    select 
        newId() as code1,
        C.*
    from
        contacts AS C
)
select 
    a.*,
    a.code1 AS code2 -- repeated same newId()
from 
    cte a
```

Comment: i have a table with thousand name and i need to change the id for each contacts, but i need 2 same id for each row

Comment: Thanks EzLo, this should answer your question @gianmarcobenedetti.